# Approach to share code between Compact Framework, Silverlight, WP7 and full .NET runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, compact-framework, shared-libraries

I am creating libraries that I will use across Compact Framework, Silverlight, WP7 and the full .NET runtime.  I am aware that the question around sharing between Compact Framework and full .NET, or between Silverlight and full .NET has been asked many times and I have been reading all the answers around that, however this situation is further complicated because I have to use VS2010 for Silverlight/WP7 and VS2008 for Compact Framework.

I therefore need to use multiple solutions along with multiple projects for this.

Is there a suggested "best-practice" approach for managing this, I am aware that I can create the multiple solutions/projects using add-file-as-link functionality to maintain the project, however this becomes a manual process open to error which I'd like to avoid.

Has anyone had any experience with automating the build of seperate frameworks, for example creating and maintaining a single .NET project, but having a custom build action which tweaks the solution and project files automatically and building several output assemblies for the different required frameworks.  I am aware there is an added complications with making sure the correct references are generated.

Is there an existing framework that achieves this, I've had a search around but can't see anything.  Alternatively is there an appetite for the creation of such a framework?

Comment: The CSLA.NET Framework uses compiler switches to achieve this - implementing framework-specific code inside the relevant switch. http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/

Comment: CSLA.NET looks interesting, I hadn't seen that one before - although I can't see a mention of Compact Framework on the page, do you know if that's supported?

Comment: Not sure if that is supported explicity, but there is a Silverlight version and I'm fairly certain I remember seeing a compact framework compiler switch in a version a while ago, perhaps the lite version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This session from PDC2010 might help:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/10/31/pdc-2010-3-screen-coding-sharing-code-between-windows-phone-silverlight-and-net.aspx

Microsoft have announced that the Portable Library Project will be available H1 this year - so it should be available real soon - maybe at Mix?

Until then, the best advice seems to be to create a SL 3 class library project for most of your sharing - WP7, WPF, SL-Web, .Net desktop - but you'll then still need to do something special for WM6 (but for WM6 I still need to do lots of special things anyway - like it still insists on using VS2008!)